# IOS6 - getting IBoutlet's frame from viewDidLoad returns 0

Tags: objective-c, uiview, autolayout, viewdidload, iboutlet

I'm working on storyboard with Autolayout. I have a viewController (i.e. myController) and I dragged in it a UIView (i.e. myView).
in myController.h I declared an IBOutlet for myView:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *myview;
```

and later I have associated this with my UI over storyboard (ctrl+dradding from myController's outlets).

The point is that I thought I could see myView's size from myController viewDidLoad Method:

```
NSLog(@"pag h:%f e w:%f",myView.frame.size.height, myview.frame.size.width);
```

But both of these outputs are 0. Where I could possibly be wrong?

Comment: once check your IBOutlet connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using autolayout, then at viewDidLoad layout has not happened yet. The frames at this point are still equal to CGRectZero when the views are loaded from the storyboard.

Log this again in viewDidAppear: and you will see the frame after layout is complete.

Comment: I'm placing a Scrollview inside myView giving the exact same frame to them (This time from viewDidAppear: method). The scrollView looks like is shifted down 20points along y axis. Do you think the problem has still something to do with autolayout? @Firoze Lafeer

Comment: If you're using autolayout in the storyboard, then you should use autolayout for the scrollview as well. Just add the scrollview with the proper constraints. Or consider not using autolayout in the storyboard, depending on your design.

Comment: What do you mean? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636186/ios-centering-uiscrollview-inside-uiview-container-resulting-in-20px-downshift