# instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier, not loading a view properly

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I am loading one of my view modally like

```
 ZViewController *zoomVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ZVC"];
```

This view has a UIScrollview and an imageview in that scrollview, both I added through Interface builder in storyboards.
The problem I have is that although I have a size and location for all of those controls in the ZVC, when I hit viewdidload in ZVC all of them are 0?

I tried implementing awakefromnib and initwithNibname but nothing!!

Comment: Are the controls actually the wrong size, or just the log of them? viewDidLoad is too early to look at frames (except for self.view). Try logging in viewDidAppear:

Comment: thanks, that was a red herring, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

After:

```
ZViewController *zoomVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ZVC"];
```

Try this:

```
[self presentViewController:zoomVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try unchecking "Use Autolayout" in IB. This might be cause of autoLayout. Do look into this for details -

[IOS6 - getting IBoutlet's frame from viewDidLoad returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634037/ios6-getting-iboutlets-frame-from-viewdidload-returns-0)